# How to sort Doctrine objects by name?

Tags: symfony, sorting, doctrine

In my Symfony Controller, in listarAction, I list all articles of the database, but I'd like to sort them by the name of article. I have this:

```
public function listarAction(Request $request) { {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $articulos = $em->getRepository("BDBundle:Articulos")->findAll();

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
                $articulos, $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 5);

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:productos_listar.html.twig', array(
            'pagination' => $pagination          
        ));
    }
}
```

How would it be the correct form? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question actually is not Symfony related. Have you read [Doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org)? I urge you to do it before you start working with it.

```
$articulos = $em->getRepository("BDBundle:Articulos")
    ->findBy([], ['name' => 'asc');
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution, more or less, but it wasn't findAll, it was findBy.

Comment: @emix it is not directly Symfony related but it is related anyway because it is common cases for people starting using Symfony with Doctrine. The solution that you provided is also described in Symfony documentation here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database